# Managing duplicate questions

Tags: discussion

Lately I have been answering a lot of questions about [karma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/karma-runner).  I have noticed that some of the questions and answers are closely related to each other.  For example, someone gets a different error than somebody else, but the root of the problem is the same, so the answer will be the same.  How can I manage these "duplicate" questions to reduce the amount of repetitious answers on SO without coming across as rude?

Comment: If the error is different, can we really say that it's a duplicate question?

Comment: I've always taken it as duplicate *questions* need to be closed. If the same root issue can present with multiple symptoms, it's not a problem to have multiple questions with the same answer; that lets others with the range of symptoms have a google target. Generally a good answer will speak to the particulars of the question anyway (explaining how the common root cause leads to *this* presentation); I don't know that I've actually seen many "different questions with duplicate answers" on the site.

Comment: @DidierL That's a good point.  However, for something like a karma configuration file, there can be a wide number of errors for the same problem.  For instance, if you leave out library dependencies, it will incrementally throw an error for each library; it complains about one, you add it, and then it complains about another one.  They are the same type of error, but are "different".  I've just seen a lot of questions posed differently for the same problem.  Most of the time it's developers that are new to using Karma in the first place.  I'm happy to help, but just want to reduce duplication.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Wait until you'll have the [Cast Close And Reopen Votes Privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions):

> Awarded At: 3,000 Reputation

that enables you to vote-to-close questions for many reasons - one of them is a duplication.

Until then, you can write a comment and link the user to the duplicate question, and you can [flag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) for closure.

Comment: Below 3k rep you can actually flag the question as a duplicate. This automatically posts a "Possible duplicate" comment with the link to the other question. The comment is automatically removed if the question is indeed closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Also, flagging (and I think VTC) as duplicate creates the auto comment linking to the other question.  So the user doesn't have to write the comment on their own.  They can always just edit the auto comment.

Answer (score 3):

If one doesn't exist yet, and you know enough about the problem domain, you can write (or find and polish) a good canonical, self-answered Q&A.

Then you can flag to close newer (and older) questions as duplicate of that canonical one.

Answer (score -9):

Perhaps its time for SO to build a Watson / Cognitive / NLP front end and trap these types of problems at source. It could learn by watching the negative comments.

This would assist both the OP in getting a quicker answer and owner from managing duplicates.